# Segment tree: amount of numbers smaller than x

Tags: algorithm, segment-tree

I'm trying to solve [this](http://www.spoj.com/problems/MKTHNUM/) problem.

I found [tutorial](http://blog.anudeep2011.com/persistent-segment-trees-explained-with-spoj-problems/#respond) for this problem but I don't get how to build segment tree that will find amount of numbers less than x in O(log n) (x can change). In tutorial it has been omitted.

Can anyone explain me how to do it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is pretty simple:

1. Store a sorted array of all numbers in a range covered by a particular node
   ( `O(n * log n)` memory and time for initialization).
2. To answer a query, decompose the query segment into `O(log n)` nodes(the same way as it is done for a standard min/max/sum segment tree) and run binary search over the array stored in each of those nodes to find the number of elements less than `x`. It gives `O(log^2 n)` time per query. You can also achieve `O(log n)` using fractional cascading, but it is not necessary.

Comment: how can we do 1 in nlogn? There are n^2 elements in the sorted ranges. Storing the sorted result itself will take n^2

Comment: @cegprakash There are O(n log n) elements because a segment tree doesn't store all ranges. It has O(log n) levels and each element is present only once at each level. A naive sort would take O(n log^2 n), but we can use merge sort for each consecutive level, making it O(n log n).